# Save figure files in R from mfuzz package

Tags: r

I want to save the figure generated by [`Mfuzz` package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Mfuzz.html). I can print the figure using this command below, but cannot save it. What do I need to do to save it in png or jpeg format?

```
mfuzz.plot2(tmp_expr,cl=cl, mfrow=c(4, 4),min.mem=0.05,xlab = "Samples", ylab="pvalue")
```

Comment: Did you try something like `png(...); mfuzz.plot2(...); dev.off()`?

Comment: @Pascal I know how to save the file with the object name "fig.prefix" but not with the mfuzz.plot2 function. 
savePlot(filename=paste(fig.prefix,".png",sep=''),type="png") ;
 Don't know how to use it for this:
mfuzz.plot2(tmp_expr,cl=cl, mfrow=c(4, 4),min.mem=0.05,xlab = "Samples", ylab="pvalue")

Comment: Did you try what I suggested or do you want to use `savePlot` only?

Comment: Sorry,but how do I get whatfilename.png here? `png(filename = "whatfilename.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", pointsize = 12, bg = "white",  res = NA, ...,
type = c("cairo", "cairo-png", "Xlib", "quartz"), antialias); mfuzz.plot2(tmp_expr,cl=cl, mfrow=c(4, 4),min.mem=0.05,xlab = "Samples",ylab="pvalue(-log10())");dev.off()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mfuzz.plot2` functions opens several plotting windows at once. The easiest solution is to store the output in a pdf format using `pdf()`. Also, the argument `x11` in `mfuzz.plot2` should be turned off using `x11 = FALSE`.

```
library(Mfuzz)

data(yeast)

yeastF <- filter.NA(yeast)
yeastF <- fill.NA(yeastF)
yeastF <- standardise(yeastF)
cl <- mfuzz(yeastF,c=20,m=1.25)

pdf("mfuzz.plot2.pdf")
mfuzz.plot2(yeastF, cl = cl, mfrow = c(2,2), x11 = FALSE)
dev.off()
```